# Show Sub pages excerpt+thumbnail

Tags: plugins, excerpt

I'm trying to show the excerpt+thumbnail of all subpages in a specific parent; I tried a bunch of plugin but no one actually works as I need; andy advice?

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin recommendation or a code sample you can modify to do what you need?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what have you tried and what your needs actually are?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually looking for a plugin that allows to show in a parent page a list with excerpts and thumbnails of all its subpages.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote code that I just put into a new page template that does exactly this. The all you do is assign the parent pages that specific template (or any page you wish to have this functionality on) and then it'll list it's child pages with their featured images as thumbs.

Getting a plugin for this would probably be kind-of complex since it all depends on the layout and styling you want as well... so just writing the code into a template like I did, is probably easiest. That way you control the look and feel too...

If you're interested in the code, let me know.

Comment: I was looking for a plugin because I thought it was a simpler solution, but I'm open to tinker with the code as well, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Sorry man, was offline for a while... Do you still need some solution here?

Comment: Oh, hi, yes, I still didn't find a complete solution to this!